# Check if string start with dot and have ':' in other place

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I check if a string is starting with a dot '`.`' and also have '`:`' in any other position?

Hoped that `^[.][:]*` should achieve that, but looks like not.

Answer (score 4):

You may use:

```
/^\..*:/s
```

Sample script:

```js
console.log(/^\..*:/s.test('.abc:def')); // true
console.log(/^\..*:/s.test('abc:def'));  // false
```

Answer (score 3):

The `^[.][:]*` pattern matches a dot at the start of the string and then zero or more colons.

You need to allow any chars other than  a `:` between the `.` and `:`:

```
/^\.[^:]*:/
```

It will match

- `^` - start of string
- `\.` - a dot
- `[^:]*` - any zero or more chars other than a `:`
- `:`  - a colon.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MKIcq6/1).

JavaScript demo:

```js
const texts = ['.abc\ndef:',  '.abc'];
const re = /^\.[^:]*:/;
for (const text of texts) {
  console.log(text, '=>', re.test(text))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might also write the check without a regex usin [startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) and  [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes):

```js
const check = s => s.startsWith(".") && s.includes(":");
[
  ".abc:def",
  ".:",
  '.abc\ndef:',
  ":.",
  "abc:def",
  ':def\n.abc',
  '.abc'
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(`${check(s)} --> ${s}`)
);
```